# How to change the interpolator(s) on a Roku Scenegraph animation node?

Tags: animation, roku, brightscript, scenegraph

Taking an example from the Roku SDK docs:

```
<Animation id="transAnimation"
       duration="1"
       repeat="true"
       easeFunction="linear" >
    <Vector2DFieldInterpolator id = "myInterp2"
        key="[0.0, 1.0]"
        keyValue="[ [640.0, 320.0], [100.0, 100.0] ]"
    fieldToInterp="myPoster.translation" />
</Animation>
```

After I've done a find on "transAnimation" is it possible to change the interpolator in brightscript code?  There are interpolators present in the XML, but after the scenegraph is built they no longer appear as children of my animation node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that, find the interpolators with m.top.findNode and modify the reverse value like so

```
myInterp2 = m.top.findNode("myInterp2")  
myInterp2.reverse = true
```

Assuming this is a toggle-able item you'll need to unset the reverse in the original animation:

```
myInterp2 = m.top.findNode("myInterp2")  
myInterp2.reverse = false
```

HOWEVER, I just went through this last week and for some reason could not get it to work on Roku 4 despite it having 7.7 (worked fine on 1, 3, and ultra but on R4 it did not reverse?!), so rather than goof around with it for hours I went back to adding a separate animation to handle the reverse.

Comment: So no way to iterate over the interpolators though?  I guess I'd need to know their names a priori.

Comment: right if you have a bunch of interpolators you need to get each one with m.top.findNode, as far as I know.